# How do I make a secure connection to a CXF service using php?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soap-client, zend-framework

I am attempting to get a SOAP client going, the only examples I get from the service provider is in Java, but I need to do this with PHP. I'm not so new to Zend, but am new to using SOAP.

I think the host service is using Apache CXF.

I am using it like this (below) and keep getting and exception 'Username not provided'

```
$wsdlprice = '/home/rob/var/www/catalog-pim/public/wsdl-docs/PriceAvailabilityService_V02.wsdl';
$client = new Zend_Soap_Client($wsdlprice, array('encoding' => 'UTF-8', 'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT));
$client->setOptions(array('login' => 'my-username', 'password' => 'my-password'));

    print_r($client);

try {
    $client->getPriceAvailability(array('hideZeroInv' => '0'));
} 
catch (SoapFault $exception) {
    echo '<br /><br /><br />EXCEPTION=' . $exception;
}
```

The errors that I am getting:

```
EXCEPTION=SoapFault exception: [soap:000101] Username is not provided in /home/rob/var/www/catalog-pim/library/Zend/Soap/Client.php:1121 Stack trace: #0 /home/rob/var/www/catalog-pim/library/Zend/Soap/Client.php(1121): SoapClient->__soapCall('getPriceAvailab...', Array, NULL, NULL, Array)
```

I took a look at Zend's 'Client.php' on line 1121 and it's the soap '__call' method. So, could be anything that PHP's soap cient does not like....like not having the 'Username'

I keep trying to add 'username', or 'Username' to the $client, I've tried adding it to 'getPriceAvailability()' method. I think I need to put it in the request header, but I cant figure that out either. I tried messing with `$client->addSoapInputHeader(new SoapHeader::$header);` but I don't know what to put into $header and I cannot seem to find much on the web.

WSDL doc:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><wsdl:definitions name="PriceAvailabilityServiceV02" targetNamespace="http://pnaV02.model.ws.synnex.com/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://pnaV02.model.ws.synnex.com/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<wsp:Policy xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UTOverTransport">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:TransportToken>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                  <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/> 
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:TransportToken>
                        <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:Basic256/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <sp:Layout>
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:Lax/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:Layout>
                        <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:TransportBinding>
                <sp:SignedSupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient"/>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:SignedSupportingTokens>
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>    
  <wsdl:types>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://pnaV02.model.ws.synnex.com/" xmlns:tns="http://pnaV02.model.ws.synnex.com/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="getPriceAvailability" type="tns:getPriceAvailability" />
    <xs:element name="getPriceAvailabilityResponse" type="tns:getPriceAvailabilityResponse" />
    <xs:complexType name="getPriceAvailability">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="skuList" type="tns:skuList" />
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="warehouse" type="tns:warehouse" />
            <xs:element name="hideZeroInv" type="xs:boolean" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="skuList">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="synnexSku" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="specialPriceType" type="tns:specialPriceType" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="mfgPartNumber" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="getPriceAvailabilityResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:pnaResponse" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="pnaResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="priceAvailabilityList" type="tns:pnaDetail" />
            <xs:element name="errorMessage" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="errorDetail" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="pnaDetail">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="synnexSku" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="mfgPartNumber" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="mfgCode" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="status" type="tns:pnaPartStatus" />
            <xs:element name="shortDescription" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="globalProductStatusCode" type="tns:pnaPartStatus" />
            <xs:element name="resellerPrice" type="xs:double" />
            <xs:element name="totalQuantity" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="totalOnOrder" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="totalBO" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="availabilityByWarehouseList" type="tns:availabilityByWarehouse" />
            <xs:element name="lineNumber" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="specialPriceType" type="tns:specialPriceType" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="availabilityByWarehouse">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="warehouseInfo" type="tns:warehouseInfo" />
            <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="ETAList" type="tns:availETA" />
            <xs:element name="OnOrder" type="xs:int" />
            <xs:element name="BO" type="xs:int" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="warehouseInfo">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="warehouse" type="tns:warehouse" />
            <xs:element name="zipCode" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="availETA">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ETA" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="QTY" type="xs:int" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="specialPriceType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="PROMOTION" />
            <xs:enumeration value="FEDERALGOVERNMENT" />
            <xs:enumeration value="STATEGOVERNMENT" />
            <xs:enumeration value="EDUCATION" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="warehouse">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="ANY" />
            <xs:enumeration value="CLOSEST" />
            <xs:enumeration value="MULTIPLE" />
            <xs:enumeration value="DNV" />
            <xs:enumeration value="DFR" />
            <xs:enumeration value="DAT" />
            <xs:enumeration value="DTX" />
            <xs:enumeration value="DCH" />
            <xs:enumeration value="DTN" />
            <xs:enumeration value="DNJ" />
            <xs:enumeration value="DDC" />
            <xs:enumeration value="DOR" />
            <xs:enumeration value="DLA" />
            <xs:enumeration value="DCC" />
            <xs:enumeration value="DOH" />
            <xs:enumeration value="DFL" />
            <xs:enumeration value="DDS" />
            <xs:enumeration value="UNKNOWN" />
            </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="pnaPartStatus">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="DISCONTINUED" />
            <xs:enumeration value="INACTIVE" />
            <xs:enumeration value="ACTIVE" />
            <xs:enumeration value="NOTAUTHORIZED" />
            <xs:enumeration value="NOTSETUP" />
            <xs:enumeration value="NOTFOUND" />
            <xs:enumeration value="UNKNOWN" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="getPriceAvailability">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getPriceAvailability" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getPriceAvailabilityResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getPriceAvailabilityResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="PriceAvailabilityService" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" wsp:PolicyURIs="#UTOverTransport">
    <wsdl:operation name="getPriceAvailability">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:getPriceAvailability" name="getPriceAvailability">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:getPriceAvailabilityResponse" name="getPriceAvailabilityResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="PriceAvailabilityServiceV02SoapBinding" type="tns:PriceAvailabilityService">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="getPriceAvailability">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input name="getPriceAvailability">
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="getPriceAvailabilityResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="PriceAvailabilityServiceV02">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:PriceAvailabilityServiceV02SoapBinding" name="PriceAvailabilityServicePort">
      <soap:address location="http://ws.synnex.com/webservice/pnaserviceV02" />
    </wsdl:port>
     <wsdl:port binding="tns:PriceAvailabilityServiceV02SoapBinding" name="PriceAvailabilityServicePort_UAT">
      <soap:address location="http://testws.synnex.com/webservice/pnaserviceV02" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question again...(not so bad though)

I discovered that I am in fact trying to connect to a CXF service http://cxf.apache.org/

This particular service uses WS Security outlined here: http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=wss

I am not the only one who has ran into this issue when attempting to connect to such a service using PHP, fortunately (for me) I found this post http://sastriawan.blogspot.com/2010/01/accessing-ws-security-protected.html

The link above clearly shows an example of how to use a class obtained from the University of Tornto's website, and another small library called 'xmlseclibs' that I found at Google Code http://code.google.com/p/xmlseclibs/

I haven't studied the 'new' code extensively yet, but it appears that it handles putting the authentication into the header of the request, and is working for me just fine.

I created a new class similar to the one on the blog that extends SoapClient and added my own auth credentials and am now able to connect to the server...only getting complaints about method variables missing...which I will fix shortly now that I can make a connection.

Comment: rhaag71 was you trying to do it for synnex data feed if yes did you done that connect if yes can you please share your code so will be helpfull for me